# Hibernate example from a tutorial don't work

Tags: hibernate, configuration

I am following an hibernate tutorial. I have created the *hibernate.cfg.xml*. 
The first example of the tutorial don't work. It throw an HibernateException reporting that the configuration is invalid when *configure* method is called. Here I left the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Session session = null;
    try {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()
        ).buildServiceRegistry();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        System.out.println("Adding a customer record !");
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setCustomerName("Customer-a");
        customer.setCustomerAddress("Address1");
        session.save(customer);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.println("Done!");
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        System.out.println("=========>" + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml is like:

```
<hibernate-configuration
xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration hibernate-configuration-4.0.xsd"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">pepe</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pepe</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernate</property>
    <property name="connection_pool_size">1</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">updated</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping resource="hibernateexample1/domain/costumer.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
```

Comment: please put link of tutorial from which you are refering this example!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably you to need to add the hibernate DOCTYPE just above hibernate-configuration, which is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
      "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd" >
```

Also check is your xml well formed, look for any unclosed tags, etc. as dont see closing for 'hibernate-configuration' tag in config file.

Comment: Thanks! A few minuts after this post I replace the code with one generated with Netbeans, and then it works. Regards